# A script to append a column with values and read multiple txt files from different folders using matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 6 folders, in each folder there is a text file with three columns omega, G' and G" with values. Want to add a new column viscosity with values and also read all the text files in just one code from different folders

```
a=readtable('Pure_melt.txt');

a1=a(:,1);

a1=table2array(a1);

b=a(:,2);

b=table2array(b);

g1=b.^2;

c=a(:,3);

c=table2array(c);

g2=c.^2;

v=sqrt(g1+g2)./a1;

f=[a1'; b'; c'; v'];

file_ID=fopen('Pure_melt.txt','w');

t='     omega        gp          gdp            vis';

fprintf(file_ID,sprintf('%s  %s  %s  %s\n',t));

fprintf(file_ID,'\n%3f%3f%3f%3f\n',f);

fclose(file_ID);
```

This is one code where I run the code for just one text file,
want to run all the 6 text file in just one code.

I did the code for one text file and was able to add the column for just one text file, repeated the procedure six times by changing the text name where each text file I saved in different folders.

I want to run all the text files by appending the column or writing in a new column in one code by reading the folder names also.